# Python DB API get inserted row id

Tags: python, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)', params) # return None
```

Azure Synapse Analytics doesn't support @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY, while `cursor.execute` returns None.

*How can I get the inserted PK (generated by `IDENTITY(1,1)`)?*

P.S. I know Synapse is columnar MPP, not an OLTP. This is needed in PoC purposes, for sake of speed development. In nearest future I will switch to appropriate RDBMs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that none of the standard T-SQL methods for retrieving new `IDENTITY` values are supported by Azure Synapse Analytics - including (`@@IDENTITY`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, `IDENT_CURRENT`, the `OUTPUT` clause, and using a sequence (via `NEXT VALUE FOR`) to set the PK value instead of `IDENTITY`)

Possibly your only option is to run a second query after the insert. Depending on the uniqueness of the inserted data, this could be as simple as:

```
SELECT ID from my_table WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ?
```

or might need to be more complex if you have to deal with duplicates.